# Suppress subfolders being listed with DIR

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this cmd bat file help me to list all the folders and sub-folders when I drag-drop the parent folder into the bat file

```
ECHO OFF

SET targetPath="%~1"
SET ToolPath=%~dp0

dir %targetPath% /s /b /o:n /a:d > "%ToolPath%listFolder.txt"
```

According to [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121(v=ws.11).aspx) about Dir command:

> Displays a list of a directory's files and subdirectories.

But is there anyway I can suppress sub-folders being listed with DIR, I just want the folders, not sub-folders.

Comment: You obviously did not read the article you referenced in your question; if you had you would have noticed what the `/S` option does...

Comment: @aschipfl: I did read it, but if I remove the `/s` option, I only get the folder name while I want the full path. So I thought `/s` is required for the full-path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `/s` switch to stop subdirectories from appearing.

```
dir %targetPath% /b /o:n /a:d > "%ToolPath%listFolder.txt"
```

To get the path with the directory:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "get-childitem -Directory %targetPath% | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }" >"%ToolPath%listFolder.txt"
```

Another way using only cmd.exe:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %f IN (`DIR /B /A:D "%targetPath%"`) DO (ECHO %~dpnxf >>"%ToolPath%listfolder.txt")
```

Comment: I did, but then it's just the folder name, not the full path. I'm finding the way to get full path.

Comment: @123iamking - I added a couple of other way that will include the directory path.